# WSO2 API Manager Custom Domain error

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have configured my wso2 with custom name by setting 
 -->
    secu.helomyl.in

```
<!--
Host name to be used for the Carbon management console
-->
<MgtHostName>secu.helomyl.in</MgtHostName>
```

It starts and i can access the url and get wso2.But the below error is in the logs.Can you please help?

[2017-02-17 14:46:32,513]  INFO - QpidServiceComponent Successfully connected to AMQP server on port 5673
[2017-02-17 14:46:32,514]  WARN - QpidServiceComponent MQTT Transport is disabled as per configuration.
[2017-02-17 14:46:32,514]  INFO - QpidServiceComponent WSO2 Message Broker is started.
[2017-02-17 14:46:32,533]  WARN - PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory Unable to create factory:Illegal character in query between indicies 66 and 1
amqp://admin:admin@clientid/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://15.100.133.77      :5673'
                                                                  ^
[2017-02-17 14:46:33,044]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Starting Pass-through HTTPS Listener...
[2017-02-17 14:46:33,047]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Check the api-manager.xml in wso2am-2.0.0/repository/conf location. There is space in the below configuration. That causes the issue.

> tcp://15.100.133.77 :5673